# ¿Cómo puedo cambiar las opciones que se cargan en un <select> en base a un valor ingresado en input text?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, validación, entrada

```
    <script languaje="javascript"> 
    function validar(){ 
        elemento = document.getElementById('nombre').value; 
        if (!elemento){ 
            window.alert("No has ingresado nada"); 
        } 
        else{  
            if (elemento >6.5) 
            {
                document.getElementById('mensaje').style.display="block";
            }
            if (elemento =< 6.5) 
            {
                document.getElementById('modelosBovedilla').style.display="block";
                document.getElementById('max39').style.display="block";
                document.getElementById('max49').style.display="block";
                document.getElementById('max57').style.display="block";
                document.getElementById('max65').style.display="block";
            }
            if (elemento =< 5.7) 
            {
                document.getElementById('max39').style.display="block";
                document.getElementById('max49').style.display="block";
                document.getElementById('max57').style.display="block";
            }
            if (elemento =< 4.9) 
            {
                document.getElementById('max39').style.display="block";
                document.getElementById('max49').style.display="block";
            }
            if (elemento =< 3.9) 
            {
                document.getElementById('max39').style.display="block";
            }


        } 
    } 
</script>

<form> 
    <input type="text" id="nombre" onkeyup="validar()"> <br>
    <select style="width:100%;background-color:#009FF0;color:white;display: none" id="modelosBovedilla" name="modelos" >
        <option value="">Seleccionar modelo</option>
        <option value="Modelo: BOVEDILLA H-18 long máx(3.90)" style="display: none" id="max39">BOVEDILLA H-18 long máx(3.90)</option>
        <option value="Modelo: BOVEDILLA H-21 long máx(4.90)" style="display: none" id="max49">BOVEDILLA H-21 long máx(4.90)</option>
        <option value="Modelo: BOVEDILLA H-25 long máx(5.70)" style="display: none" id="max57">BOVEDILLA H-25 long máx(5.70)</option>
        <option value="Modelo: BOVEDILLA H-31 long máx(6.50)" style="display: none" id="max65">BOVEDILLA H-31 long máx(6.50)</option>
    </select>
    <h1 id="mensaje" style="display: none">NO HAY BOVEDILLAS CON QUE CUMPLAN CON ESA MEDIDA</h1>
</form>
```

El código mostrado es lo que actualmente tengo.

Cabe decir que la validación tiene que ser en tiempo real, ósea si ingreso un número mayor a 10 me va a mostrar unas opciones de la lista y si es menor de 10 me muestra otras opciones.

Comment: ¿qué has intentado hasta ahora?

Comment: Estoy intentando hacerlo con Jquery y/o Javascript pero no me funciona

Comment: A lo que me refiero, es que dejes una porción de lo que intentas en código, para poder ayudarte, sino es más complicado!

Comment: he, actualizado mi pregunta con el código que tengo.

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres usar jQuery puedes usar el evento `input` al igual que otros más como `keypress` o `keydown` entre otros, luego, solo deberías evaluar tu condición y modificar el `value` del `select` en cuestión utilizando `.val()`

```js
//Detecto el evento de cambio en el <input>
$('input').on('input',function(){

 //Chequeo, si está vacío
 if($(this).val().length == 0)
 {
 //Selecciono la opción 2
 $('select').val('2');
 return;
 }

 //Chequeo si es menor que 0
 if($(this).val() < 0)
 {
    //Selecciono la opción 0
   $('select').val('0');
 }
 //Cualquier otro caso
 else
 { 
    //Selecciono la opción 1
   $('select').val('1');
 }
});
```

```css
input,select
{
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 22px;
  width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="number">
<br>
<select>
<option value="0">negativo</option>
<option value="1">positivo</option>
<option value="2" selected="selected">vacio</option>
</select>
```

Saludos

Comment: Lo intentaré con esta forma ¡muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

quizás busques algo como esto (con permiso del compañero @Juan salvador Portugal, pongo la respuesta sin JQuery por si le resulta útil):

```
<input type="number" id="tu_input">
<br>
<select id="tu_select">
    <option value="0">negativo</option>
    <option value="1">positivo</option>
    <option value="2" selected="selected">vacio</option>
</select>



var select = document.getElementById("tu_select");
var input = document.getElementById("tu_input");

input.addEventListener("keyup", function(){
    var numero_introducido = input.value;
    if(numero_introducido < 0){
        select.selected = 0;  
     }else if (numero_introducido > 0){
        select.selected = 1;
     }else{
        select.selected = 2;
     }
});
```

Comment: Lo intentaré, ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Con un condicional.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="text" id="miTexto" />
<select id="miCombo">
<select>

<script>
   var mayores = [{"codigo":"opt1","descripcion":"opcion 1"}, {"codigo":"opt2","descripcion":"opcion 2"},{"codigo":"opt3","descripcion":"opcion 3"}];
   var menores= [{"codigo":"opt10","descripcion":"opcion 10"}, {"codigo":"opt20","descripcion":"opcion 20"},{"codigo":"opt30","descripcion":"opcion 30"}];

   $("#miTexto").on("change",function(){
   $('#miCombo').empty();

     if($(this).val()>10){
       $.each(mayores, function (index, item) {
            $("#miCombo").append($("<option>", {value: item[codigo], text:item[descripcion] }));
        });
     }else{
       $.each(menores, function (index, item) {
            $("#miCombo").append($("<option>", {value: item[codigo], text:item[descripcion] }));
        });
     }
   });
</script>
```